# Xamarin forms iOS build fails in Mobile Center

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I get the following message when trying to build an Xamarin Forms app in Mobile Center.

Any help or clue what is causing the error would be appreciated.  Thanks.

[image: Mobile Center Upload error]

Comment: I no longer get this error.  I am not sure the exact reason, but I think it had to do the nuget.config file.  I replaced it with an earlier version I had as a copy and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue when renaming or changing ownership of an app.

If you encounter this, please contact us with the app details through the support interface (blue chat bubble button on the lower right corner of the portal) and we will be happy to help.

We are working on a permanent fix for this.